# Astoria vs. SQL Server Data Services

Tags: ado.net, astoria, ssds

What are in your opinion big differences between areas of usage for "Astoria" (ADO.NET data services) and SQL Server Data Services?

Answer (score 5):

They are similiar but very different technologies. Astoria or what is now called at [Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) is a programming library that will allow data to be passed through RESTful web services.  You develop these web services to be run against data you have access to.  ADO.NET Data Services is now included in the .NET 3.5 SP1 updates.

[SQL Server Data Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/dataservices/default.mspx) is a new service provided by Microsoft.  The following is a decription:

> *"SQL Server Data Services (SSDS) are highly scalable, on-demand data
>   storage and query processing utility
>   services. Built on robust SQL Server
>   database and Windows Server
>   technologies, these services provide
>   high availability, security and
>   support standards-based web interfaces
>   for easy programming and quick
>   provisioning."*

SQL Server Data Services is very similair to Amazon S3 service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can call both Astoria and SQL Data Services with the same code in your app.  So it depends on where you want your data - on your servers or in the cloud.